# Scan through directories c++

Tags: c++, directory, multiplatform

What would be the best way to recursively scan through a directory in c++? This is supposed to run on all operating systems so which api would work best?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

http://compressionratings.com/d_archiver_template.html
http://compressionratings.com/s_scan.html